# Using regex to match with patterns like <some_pattern>Dog<the_exact_pervious_pattern>Cat

Tags: regex, perl

Is it possible to write a regex in Perl that matches with strings like

```
<some_pattern>Dog<the_exact_pervious_pattern>Cat
```

or in other words it would match with
`CarDogCarCat`  `ChairDogChairCat`

but not with `ChairDogCarCat`

to substitute it with another text. I don't care about the exact characters that form `<some_pattern>` or `<the_exact_pervious_pattern>`, I only care that both of the them has the exact same characters.
I tried something like

```
s/(.*(Dog)?)Cat/replacement/g;
```

But I know that would match with `ChairDogCarCat`, also tried

```
s/(.*)Dog$1Cat/replacement/g;
```

but it didn't work. Is that something that I can't do with regex and would need other string processing functions (i.e. splitting) to implement? Regex always seems to be the easier and shorter solution for me but I don't know if it has limitations with some patterns.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a capture group for `<some_pattern>`, then reference it later on in the regex as `\1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [relative backreference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Relative-backreferences)

```
/(.*?) Dog \g{-1} Cat/x
```

This is if you don't need to capture `Dog`. If you do, then count off one further back

```
/(.*?)(Dog)\g{-2}(Cat)/
```

where the `{-2}` means to match the same subpattern as the second last capture.

Answer (score 2):

Create a capture group, and back-reference it with `\1`. Your example:

```
/([A-Z][a-z]+)Dog\1Cat/
```

Examples:

```
CarDogCarCat     ==> match
ChairDogChairCat ==> match
ChairDogCarCat   ==> no match
```